# Speaker / sound icon doesn't change in menu bar in Big Sur?

Tags: audio, headphones, icon, menu-bar

This is a very minor thing, but when headphones were connected under Catalina/Mojave, the sound icon on the menu bar would change to let you know they had connected. But under Big Sur, it doesn't change. Is there any way to get it to change so that there is a visual cue that the sound device has connected?

[image]

We can still click on the sound icon to find out which device is connected, I just wonder if there's a way to avoid having to do that:

[image]

Comment: For me on Big Sur, it shows when my wired headphones are connected, and shows the normal volume icon when they are disconnected. However, I don't use bluetooth headphones/airplay. Additionally, when I click on the volume menu icon, I don't see any of the output options as per your screenshot other than "Internal Speakers" or "Headphones", depending on whether my headphones are connected or not. I'm not why you have so many outputs listed when you click the volume menu bar item, but I can only ever see one output on my MacBook Pro late-2013 model. Strange